# User stories for functional requirements

Tags: project-management, user-stories, agile-project-management

As we are a small company, I work as both a project manager and developer.  The specifications I create for clients contain a number of elements used to describe and define the project, including user stories alongside any other elements I feel need to be included to define the project (e.g. wireframes, userflows, sitemaps etc.) to the client.

If a functional specification “describes how a product will work entirely from the user's perspective. It doesn't care how the thing is implemented. It talks about features.“.  Then does anyone see any problem with using User Stories to define a functional specification for a website?  Does anyone actually do functional specifications in this way?

Really I am trying to up my game a little, and wondering if this would approach would work for larger clients who perhaps have more stringent ideas on what a functional specification should contain, whereby a formal approach may be required.  Definitely at the moment our clients respond well to our method of producing documentation.

I am interested in hearing what people who do project management professionally think about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm at odds with what a couple of other people have said.

First up the bit I agree with - stories are a great way of stating functional requirements.  For my money they're one of the best ways of actually communicating requirements in a way end users will really take in.  I've seen too many specs that get signed off without ever having been read.

The one thing I would say you might want to append to them is non-functional requirements - covering performance, security, data volumes, audit, archive and so on.  While they can be covered in stories, sometimes they're better covered in a way that crosses all stories.

In terms of whether it's suitable for large companies this is where I disagree.  In my experience (and I've done projects for Shell, American Express, a couple of multi-national banks and others) they're often no more formal than smaller companies so they'll be fine with stories.  The reality is that a user in a large company is no better equiped (or interested) in reading class and sequence diagrams than they are elsewhere.

The size and complexity of the project may require more detailed requirements but it's the size of the project, not the size of the company that matters when you're determining how you document requirements.

For me the best requirements documentation is documentation that's suited to it's audience, and for me user stories hit the nail on the head most of the time - they're short enough and clear enough that when they sign them off they mean something because they've read and understood them (as opposed to the sign off of a 100 page spec which invariably means they haven't really read it), but good enough for the developers to work from too.

Comment: Thanks for that reply - that was very helpful - and I agree with all your points.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use user stories for your functional requires. I do it all the time, and have been for years. In my opinion, it works really well, and better than other systems I have used.

Would this approach work for larger clients? To make a gross generalization, no. They are going to have some system that use to define requirements, and likely its not user stories. If you come in with user stories, there is going to be a disconnect with the current practices, which you will have to work through.

I have been successful using user stories with larger organizations, but it take a concerted effort, which both parties need to be committed to.

Comment: Interesting comments all. However, even the folks that invented Agile agree that "User Story" != "Use Case" or functional requirement. That is, I dunno ... 20 years later I still would not know how to correctly implement the User Story "Student must be able to buy a parking pass". There are a lot of details in functional requirements beyond the 1-2 sentence story. So the submission may be via a forged email from an unverified student to which the system would issue the parking pass? I daresay that User Stories are not by any stretch "actionable requirements".

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing are the use-case scenarios that define the features, this is what is required from a usability perspective and is exactly what the client will understand and agree to. Screen mockups and flow diagrams will definately help both the client and developers.

An implementation specification may then be required to instruct developers on what needs to be included in the actual construction, the depth of this will be determined by your developers capabilities that include their knowledge of the house architecture/framework and methodologies/conventions and may include specifics on what impacts various parts of the application.

We also work in small teams (sometimes one or two developers) and believe the above is all that's required in this instance.

Larger companies with much larger teams may use Modeling Software, UML diagrams and other more detailed specifications. In the case where you the primary developer, you should still spend the time designing your application, but if nobody is going to review the designs and insist on all the formalities, your time is better spend implementing the software.